# Иконки в Toolbar не отображается

Tags: android, icon, toolbar

Иконки в toolbar не отображаются в design окне и эмуляторе (текст в toolbar отображается). Я перепробовала уже несколько способов создать Toolbar и ActionBar, но ни один способ не сработал. Остановилась на этом:
java файл не меняла.
activity_main.xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/teal_700">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left_icon"
            android:layout_width="66dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:icon="@drawable/a" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/left_icon"
            android:text="lalalallallalalalla" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/right_icon"
            android:layout_width="77dp"
            android:layout_height="67dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 1) RelativeLayout внутри RelativeLayout это избыточно, 2) RelativeLayout устарел, лучше использовать ConstraintLayout, 3) В вашем случае не нужен RelativeLayout или ConstraintLayout, а достаточно LinearLayout

Comment: Попробуйте переписать ваш `toolbar.xml` на `LinearLayout` c `orientation=horizontal`, внутри будет ImageView, TextView и ImageView и больше никакой вложенности.

Answer (score 3):

Вместо этого:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
```

Сделайте так:

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
```

Есть мнение что icon только в манифесте используется, для ссылки на иконку приложения.

Comment: Да, все верно, с `src` будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!